# Tables in ":memory:' database

Tags: sqlite

I have a :memory: database. I want to create 5 tables in that database. which is best normal tables/temp tables? Will the tables automatically get delete when we close the connection?

I am planning to use sqlite_sequence table to get the last inserted id of the table. Is there any sqlite_sequence table in :memory: database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:memory:` just like an ordinary database, with normal tables. All data and schema will be lost once you close the connection or quit the process.

The `sqlite_sequence` table will be there whenever there are tables with autoincrement columns, however, you could just use `last_insert_rowid()` SQL function.

Comment: Can you tell me which is faster temp tables or normal tables?

Comment: @Sandy For in-memory database, normal tables will not be slower than temporary ones.